# Why do I only get one result of TF-IDF?

Tags: java, tf-idf

```
// Calculating term frequency
    System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scan.nextLine();

    String[] array = word.split(" ");
    int filename = 11;
    String[] fileName = new String[filename];
    int a = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;


    for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {

        try {
            System.out.println("The word inputted is " + word);
            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc" + a
                            + ".txt");
            System.out.println(" _________________");

            System.out.print("| File = abc" + a + ".txt | \t\t \n");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                totalCount = 0;
                wordCount = 0;

                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                {
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        totalCount++;
                        if (s.next().equals(array[i]))
                            wordCount++;

                    }

                    System.out.print(array[i] + " ---> Word count =  "
                            + "\t\t " + "|" + wordCount + "|");
                    System.out.print("  Total count = " + "\t\t " + "|"
                            + totalCount + "|");
                    System.out.printf("  Term Frequency =  | %8.4f |",
                            (double) wordCount / totalCount);

                    System.out.println("\t ");

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found");

        }

    }

System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word2 = scan2.nextLine();
    String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");
    int numofDoc;

    for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {

        numofDoc = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {

            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc"
                                + i + ".txt"));

                int matchedWord = 0;

                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(in);

                {

                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        if (s2.next().equals(array2[b]))
                            matchedWord++;
                    }

                }
                if (matchedWord > 0)
                    numofDoc++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(array2[b]
                + " --> This number of files that contain the term  "
                + numofDoc);
        double inverseTF = Math.log10((float) numDoc / numofDoc);
        System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> IDF " +  inverseTF );
        double TFIDF = (((double) wordCount / totalCount) * inverseTF );
        System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> TFIDF " + TFIDF);
    }
}
```

Hi, this is my code for calculating term frequency and TF-IDF. The first code calculates the term frequency for each file of a given string. The second code is supposed to calculate TF-IDF for each file using the value from the above. But I only received one value. It's supposed to provide TF-IDF value for each document.

Example output for term frequency :

The word input is 'is'

---

| File = abc0.txt |
is ---> Word count =         |2|  Total count =          |150|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0133 |

The word inputted is 'is'

---

| File = abc1.txt |
is ---> Word count =         |0|  Total count =          |9|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0000 |

The TF-IDF

is --> This number of files that contain the term  7

is --> IDF 0.1962946357308887

is --> TFIDF 0.0028607962606519654  <<< I suppose to get one value per file, means that i have 10 files, it suppose to give me 10 different values for each different file. But, it only prints one result only. Can someone point my mistake?

Comment: Aside from the actual answer (as given by Howard) you should pay more attention to naming. Having variables called "fileName" and "filename", one of which is an `int`, is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part that prints the TDIDF needs to be moved inside the for loop that loops over all the files.

ie:

```
    System.out.println(array2[b]
            + " --> This number of files that contain the term  "
            + numofDoc);
    double inverseTF = Math.log10((float) numDoc / numofDoc);
    System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> IDF " +  inverseTF );
    double TFIDF = (((double) wordCount / totalCount) * inverseTF );
    System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> TFIDF " + TFIDF);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

The println statement you suppose to be repeated per file is

```
double TFIDF = (((double) wordCount / totalCount) * inverseTF );
System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> TFIDF " + TFIDF);
```

but it is contained in the single loop

```
for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++)
```

only. If you want to print this line per file you have to surround this statement by another loop over all files.

Since this is homework I won't include the final code, but give you another hint: you also included the variables wordCount and totalCount in the calculation of TFIDF. But these are unique to each filename/word pair. Therefore you need to save it not only once, but per filename/word or recaclulate them again in your final loop.